# What are trackbacks?

Tags: pages

I was wondering what are trackbacks. I found this to be an option in Wordpress, and I am wondering if I should add them to pages and posts. Thank you for your help and support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trackbacks (and their close relatives pingbacks) are rather well documented in Codex under [Managing Comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Managing_Comments). Essentially it's a form of automated comment which other sites can use to notify they have something relevant to specific post.

Note that just as normal comments these are very heavily spammed and some form of antispam is a must.